# FindInFiles does not work properly and I would like to open the file on click

Tags: vb.net

I am using FindInFiles to find files using words entered by user. It doesnot work all the time. I can find some words but most of words are not searched by program.

```
 Dim myDocumentsPath As String = tree.SelectedNode.FullPath
        ' Look for the string "Visual Basic" in all document files in this 
        ' directory tree, in case-insensitive mode.
        Dim files As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String) =
           My.Computer.FileSystem.FindInFiles(MyApp.LastPath, txtFindText.Text, True,
           FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)
        ' Show all file names in a listbox.
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each file As String In files
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file))
```

Comment: Can you give a few examples on what did not work as expected?

Comment: When I search for words that are in the files, It doesn't find those files. Gives me a blank window with no results.

Comment: Are all the files you are searching plain text?

Comment: Not in plain Text

Comment: You could look into using Windows Search, e.g. [Using Windows Search in your applications](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Using_Windows_Search_in_your_applications.aspx).